# Swift - UITableViewController and Storyboard not linked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-storyboard

[image]

I am adding a UITableViewController and created it programatically for a reason.
I also assigned this custom controller to my storyboard. However, when I run it, it doesn't seem like they are linked because I don't see the cell header ("Suggestion" in the screenshot below). If I set this controller to an initial controller, I can see it thou. Having this said, it is something to do with creating my controller programatically? Please advice me what is missing..

[image]

UPDATE:
It is actually a part of creating a UISearchController. Here is my code snippet.

```
    searchResultController = CustSearchGoogleResultTableViewController()
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultController)
```

Comment: How you are creating the UITableViewController? Is it possible for you  to share code?

Comment: @BhagyalaxmiPoojary I just edited the question. Please have a look at it again. Thank you in advance.

Comment: your question is not clear -david park

Comment: Since you aren't instantiating your view controller from the storyboard it won't have any of the information you have defined in the storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply creating an instance of a view controller as you are won't get any of the details that you have configured in the storyboard.

You need to use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` and to do this you need to put an identifier into the storyboard scene - on the right of your screen shot where it says "Storyboard ID", say 'searchController'.  Once you have done that you can use

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let searchResultController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("searchController") as! CustSearchGoogleResultTableViewController
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultController)
```

Comment: thank you thank you!!!!! this is exactly what i wanted and solved my problem...i really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

You are only creating it. You also need to add it to the view . This may help you.

```
searchResultController = CustSearchGoogleResultTableViewController()
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultController)
self.view.addSubView(searchController.view)
```